# MAN pages are not displaying properly

Tags: command-line, 16.04, manpage

[man ls command output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70F7i.png)

My man pages are not displaying properly in Ubunut 16.04
The command line arguments are not displaying, instead of them comma is being displayed as shown in attached image above.

Kindly provide some solution for this.

Comment: Try to change the foreground and background color of the terminal from Terminal Preferences.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli It worked. The arguments were in black colour in dark theme. I changed colour of bold letters in profile preferences. Now they are displaying.
Thank you